# iptables forwarding rule

Tags: firewall, iptables

I entered the following rule into my iptables:

```
 sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1337
```

and then when I went to remove it, I couldn't find it anywhere with iptables -L
Why is this, and how can I remove it? Thank you!

Edit: I have ufw installed, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

To view NAT Rules use

`iptables -t nat -L -n -v`

not only `iptables -L`